# Random native crashes on a webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm experiencing random native crashes on android webview. The error log doesn't say much to me, I have no idea what it can be. This happens most of times on Samsung devices, like Galaxy J7. The log error is:

```
11-28 15:37:15.635 3355-3355/? V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{fc241ad token=android.os.BinderProxy@5100c59 {com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity}} show : false
11-28 15:37:15.635 2608-2863/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
11-28 15:37:15.635 2608-2608/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
11-28 15:37:15.635 2608-2803/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1300000  uid : 1000  pid : 2608  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@13
11-28 15:37:15.635 2608-2608/? I/KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
11-28 15:37:15.635 2608-2608/? I/KnoxTimeoutHandler: Fullscreen and mCurrent is not KNOX user. Hence hide keyguard
11-28 15:37:15.645 2166-2166/? D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xff988904
11-28 15:37:15.645 3355-3355/? D/Launcher: onTrimMemory. Level: 20
11-28 15:37:15.645 2608-2863/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is false showWhenlocked is true
11-28 15:37:15.645 2608-2608/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is false showWhenlocked is true
11-28 15:37:15.645 2608-2608/? I/KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
11-28 15:37:15.675 2166-2166/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xff98888c
11-28 15:37:16.065 2608-3293/? D/GpsLocationProvider_ex: SV Count : 11(0) / TOP5(v) : 20 20 17 16 9  / TOP5(u) : 
11-28 15:37:16.185 3168-3168/? D/Recents: onTaskStackChanged
11-28 15:37:16.205 2166-3331/? I/display: [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(0)
11-28 15:37:16.235 2608-2608/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1300000  uid : 1000  pid : 2608  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@13
11-28 15:37:16.235 2608-2608/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: FrequencyrequestList.getNextCStateDisableRequest, index: 1
11-28 15:37:16.365 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
11-28 15:37:16.365 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: V AndroidWebView:62.0.3202.84
11-28 15:37:16.365 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: O A arm 08 armv8l samsung/j7elteub/j7elte:6.0.1/MMB29K/J700MUBS2BQEB:user/release-keys
11-28 15:37:16.365 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: P webview
11-28 15:37:16.365 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: R 0000000B SIGSEGV F4C80D08
11-28 15:37:16.365 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: G 
11-28 15:37:16.375 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: H 12C00000 FFEFB000 0093 31185000 7C482000 0C:0F 0D:07 0E:0C 0F:0B 10:0D 11:0C 12:11 13:14 14:0D 15:06 16:07 17:04 18:04 19:02 1B:01 1C:01 1D:02
11-28 15:37:16.375 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: S 0 D837A690 D837A000 00003000
...
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M AB11D000 00000000 0000B000 91A1824A19C3B0A299CF3D4242756FB10 app_process32
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M 70C6B000 00000000 0532C000 8667326CF3A72415531638EB389AD4030 boot.oat
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M DAF5D000 00000000 004B0000 8668EFF64EBECC37FF5B3D9625F32DF70 base.odex
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M DC736000 00000000 0163B000 F69F6D578EEBA878877880179349B6AA0 libGLES_mali.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E0911000 00000000 01A93000 71D98F81E713144AE5E2DAF9455010930 base.odex
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E35BF000 00000000 025C3000 E3065D0EF4DDBD0918FC74D1C60718AF0 libwebviewchromium.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9E47000 00000000 00018000 EE599EDFB3882DF22B5EC33D651E91BE0 libkeymaster1.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9E62000 00000000 00009000 91753D758E498CBBBB45DA264A17DE420 libkeymaster_messages.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9E6D000 00000000 00014000 65A4AFD2AD5238B829D93026315800D70 libsoftkeymasterdevice.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9E84000 00000000 0000C000 049954DA62C4C45D0A010A22F5EFAD250 libkeystore_binder.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9E93000 00000000 00004000 E279F216CB0FDE9D4BCD54792F4784F10 libkeystore-engine.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9E99000 00000000 00007000 24C688031D1AAD7ED562B3E58A6AEF130 libucsengine.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9EA2000 00000000 00009000 E41B80486C9DEBB645087BC599F45EF90 libsecpkcs11_engine.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9EAD000 00000000 00017000 1522636199AF6F1766902CB99E5EA1A80 libjavacrypto.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9EC7000 00000000 0000E000 5B7E5E3B3AECC927243BEF1244CBF3D30 libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9ED4000 00000000 00021000 4AABA64E06BAA4B344C3F7E79255DC990 libexif.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9F03000 00000000 00015000 62CF3115E3DED2144FBF52796CC753DD0 libmtp.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M E9F19000 00000000 00046000 71FCA759C9EB35F6E6923A7768CF6EB70 libmedia_jni.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M EA01F000 00000000 00008000 CE5742D4D89CDEDEE443787148D542240 libcompiler_rt.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M EA028000 00000000 0000F000 F5ED3F1ACA28D6671B8D603D121453BF0 libandroid.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M EB840000 00000000 00004000 C65354F75652480A5BD617FFCA5339930 libwebviewchromium_loader.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M EE750000 00000000 00004000 E55DF3C3192561E0CA15295F3CCD62B60 libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M EE95D000 00000000 00004000 44CBF83E02B50A40C5FDAB54F0D67A600 memtrack.exynos5.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M EE963000 00000000 00003000 F3689409BB1DD6599378E952D41EF3A60 libjnigraphics.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M EE9A5000 00000000 00005000 CB0974A363341E54F1ACFEA0C3EB67820 gralloc.exynos5.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F0188000 00000000 00035000 D4741D0CAD27D26FC6AD99588918A3220 libjavacore.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F3427000 00000000 00003000 0237FB6360095A8B13796C48AD10A9520 libion.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F4357000 00000000 0045C000 2C3FA3D0E49C3FEB3CA2B97D3A3C99CA0 libart.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F48F7000 00000000 00A44000 0F813AA3ECCD40A09555B4EACABFE1FE0 libLLVM.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F538E000 00000000 00036000 88340B57756B1814E972226C8513A3800 libbcinfo.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F53C6000 00000000 00058000 734F3875E6FD5C4A40A1B6060874BE1B0 libbcc.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5421000 00000000 0000B000 960B7650EF8D44EBD561141A414EF2F30 libcommon_time_client.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5430000 00000000 00017000 B98EFBB4AFCCAB99DF20B7EE3A7ADB480 libprotobuf-cpp-lite.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F544A000 00000000 0000A000 683A6B3599F66F5B3FB17C74A6EBEA320 libsec_km.so
11-28 15:37:16.395 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5456000 00000000 00004000 C2DAAD976FF58B60214C62A62B1BC9310 libSEF4MP4.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F545C000 00000000 00017000 D1D5D60025C40837EB36576351B0B06C0 libSEF.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5475000 00000000 0000D000 6A671567EF8C47DA43552CEF88BC391E0 libsfextcp.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5484000 00000000 0005D000 098C11FE4C21578382788600EA30FAB50 libsavsff.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F54E8000 00000000 00062000 1AE5E6C18D36B58FA8119C6CAABC04870 libsavscmn.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F554B000 00000000 0004F000 4B1C393113CA11DC9518EBAA2B7FD0700 libomafldrm.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F559F000 00000000 00007000 AD9B054314E90C48C446B3190049799A0 libstagefright_avc_common.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F55A8000 00000000 00003000 5A5774B9C17209ECDBA17571D76ADCA80 libstagefright_enc_common.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F55AE000 00000000 00004000 9B2B11E344BB37D529E0F5310086CAC40 libpowermanager.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F55B5000 00000000 0001D000 0755AA0DABAD29AD08A5F4F2CC0BCD6D0 libvorbisidec.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F55D4000 00000000 00005000 8502BDE527913A72B5567C31CB65722C0 libstagefright_yuv.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F55DA000 00000000 00033000 5151625515CA547E6FE3338F9122D7A30 libstagefright_omx.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5611000 00000000 0003B000 D902C56FD24E87AED80D22B48C76177A0 libopus.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F564E000 00000000 00007000 441B66301085D808B5E5D561B4C7A8E00 libmediautils.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5657000 00000000 00018000 305EE5213958DA508FC32ECE9587FCC30 libdrmframework.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5675000 00000000 0001F000 9ADB890D07EA0FF92E7D5941B607996C0 libRScpp.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5696000 00000000 0003E000 873E7BC06439D3B47A4590015888FA010 libRS.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F56D8000 00000000 00007000 D4776A3404D19D7AEC38192C6718CE850 libspeexresampler.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F56E1000 00000000 00006000 CDA94FBA9F421C3BD04C343C923FAD870 libedmnativehelper.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F56EA000 00000000 00009000 227EC3FB0CD2679ECCD486A04E16D5230 libnbaio.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F56F5000 00000000 00091000 D03D5B396D8CB13D65D2C794AABB5C4A0 libcrypto-rename.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5793000 00000000 00012000 702FC4EF6F7F697A0AE6D0BF717729F60 libpcre.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F57A7000 00000000 00005000 19BE594F377F04E31C2A1AB6EF5A8AD50 libwpa_client.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F57AF000 00000000 0006D000 15ECC6AE261F9D4D0D966B7C5215E07A0 libGLES_trace.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5821000 00000000 00007000 F1F25DDE92B301357E916971ECE3579E0 libsdp_crypto.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F582A000 00000000 00080000 C2C31DC3179CD839FE6D1290DA7BB75A0 libAstcEnc.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F58C4000 00000000 00020000 A342A17113B2CF45EE3A8C34ED76C6C90 libquramimagecodec.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F58E6000 00000000 00061000 7EE2F6688F794F00577A22EE6BFC81200 libft2.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F594A000 00000000 00025000 EBA43C63D6D3A21B8249005B154A542B0 libpng.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5970000 00000000 00009000 AF2FD289E8094D090A2CE52A33FD271F0 libremotedesktop_client.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F597C000 00000000 00003000 B5A174FFFD3A4568EFC2C32E771ACED70 libsync.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5981000 00000000 00004000 69BA20F3B851B57E6404A0395229E58A0 libstdc++.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5988000 00000000 00010000 7EAA1C1E5221B487D69955689A56BBB70 libunwind.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F59E1000 00000000 00009000 035E47C0AE9A3109F06CA50E823B0E760 libbase.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F59EC000 00000000 00005000 1B40B293B02556A7175A4FCB940D227C0 libeffects.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F59F3000 00000000 00003000 D8E0220D0411EDC56A20C1E0FAF1ACD90 libstagefright_http_support.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F59F9000 00000000 00018000 506DBBEEA6D6ED262D0E4CC544A6F2A40 libstagefright_foundation.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5A0D000 00000000 001A0000 80EC8AF0445FD727DC2DE6227C2D7F680 libstagefright.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5BBB000 00000000 00004000 441FB43FA1DD33273C6B9AC7D62F344B0 libpersona.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5BC2000 00000000 00010000 DADADC8ABF80DE85246A563354D808EC0 libimagefilter.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5BD4000 00000000 00011000 2FE1F87DA2F794774055E62AE737B7740 libsamsungeffect.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5BE8000 00000000 00019000 2A10F34BF7020C0E467DC0B7568A91DE0 libmctraster.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5C08000 00000000 00078000 76F9455DEC72598252A1B13B01641B4B0 libhwui.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5C85000 00000000 00003000 D2F1603EB0AA7B9B6D8966B3B804EE3C0 libcc_manager.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5C8A000 00000000 00005000 142629F982E508301963D2F116CB0A970 libsecnativefeature.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5C92000 00000000 00003000 1F5DEED54F573B92CD1CD5FF51B55B1D0 libradio_metadata.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5C97000 00000000 00004000 FFA7DB8ED59C43FD1AEFED4B3BBC09400 libnativebridge.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5C9D000 00000000 00004000 85D9C60572688BBE838DAF63ED585EF30 libprocessgroup.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5CA3000 00000000 0000E000 04BACA9A897BE79EBECEBED4437556A90 libminikin.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5CB3000 00000000 0000B000 B4A61E952C22BE2AFF252D718C8733FE0 libsoundtrigger.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5CC1000 00000000 0000B000 B2CCF1786A17C50B68E9BE59DE220C460 libradio.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5CD1000 00000000 00004000 EE61D6F93D2AE059BAB57735531723F10 libnetd_client.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5CD7000 00000000 0000D000 72754AC8B407F7840CDCE70E26F80B7A0 libimg_utils.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F5CE1000 00000000 00418000 329C2D8C6165970F215E45669F9DC3330 libpdfium.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6108000 00000000 00007000 7B649A377B17140DF76AF794B0379E760 libaudioutils.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6111000 00000000 0001B000 DCBB13F16F3CE4511167DDF5DA3C29120 libz.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F612E000 00000000 0004C000 59248D54E335D88955FE841D0410FC290 libharfbuzz_ng.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F617D000 00000000 00004000 92418B6D58FC7B116E51CBE4212BDD980 libusbhost.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6184000 00000000 00038000 E7DFD971D16E80859B27CBFAE2B786830 libjpeg.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F61A5000 00000000 000B9000 DB0F8BCABC1F412C95B7FA1CD701A4120 libmedia.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6277000 00000000 0017A000 A7BCAEEA15F9CF83C701EB172AC37E170 libicui18n.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F63F6000 00000000 0011E000 3DF6821D2FBEEBC4DDFAD6CDB1BAA15C0 libicuuc.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6524000 00000000 00024000 F6533A94867040BE3BE39AF806E292450 libssl.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F654B000 00000000 000A6000 96C8CEF9EA1CF699F1F9A058AFC421100 libcrypto.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6601000 00000000 00053000 F0D251BB32B369B0D649F395F3FEC9BD0 libsonivox.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F665C000 00000000 00012000 FFDFD997E8376A84D84304D04F24F9300 libselinux.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6671000 00000000 00008000 67F6A794FC960DFA80F77286E3C95A5F0 libhardware_legacy.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F667C000 00000000 00004000 F6AD952F314BD1A230E231DEC5D1D3B30 libhardware.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6682000 00000000 00004000 881E51D1180F993EEDCD22103EFB83510 libETC1.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6688000 00000000 00010000 5638D8493EBCE4A67F79CBD4CFEC606E0 libGLESv2.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F669A000 00000000 0000A000 1236D057A8B248DBC8D7C894390F966D0 libGLESv1_CM.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F669E000 00000000 0006E000 B955920416C268C319A959EB7CD7AD290 libEGL.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F671A000 00000000 00098000 79133EC7C454B2975B509A41AF3FDFE20 libsqlite.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F67A4000 00000000 003D5000 D68A40ABD59BFB32726428351A5CAA840 libskia.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6B9F000 00000000 00008000 ADB03CD5883901F9B9DF77B71FF9B55A0 libcamera_metadata.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6BA5000 00000000 00035000 DF025354DB75C34F3A55A9EBA4FBE6740 libcamera_client.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6BE1000 00000000 00046000 ACD967627F4B852DE7E1740232B2FAB80 libinputflinger.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6C2A000 00000000 0001D000 038931EC200B425A2229F644A4368CFA0 libinput.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6C43000 00000000 00057000 189228C3C3EE017C45C1FE0D0E18D3830 libgui.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6CA8000 00000000 0000D000 53E5B04F573D44FFDAD00A47161B2C020 libui.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6CB8000 00000000 00008000 A2721C015023E9F96BE2D91372126EB50 libnetutils.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6CC3000 00000000 00007000 0CB4D6FC5A7B9752C425978F5280C1D50 libnativehelper.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6CCC000 00000000 00014000 47DA6C7A1AC041551FFCAD09E0E4231D0 libexpat.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6CE3000 00000000 00028000 ED2626BCFE2D0E3558590E4D235305DB0 libandroidfw.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6D0E000 00000000 00003000 D04F43839597AEA462211CF3A7586C630 libmemtrack.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6D13000 00000000 00009000 0367E5F0C585FC3D8E07163869FA42770 libbacktrace.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6D1E000 00000000 00020000 BB25149F76A1175C911E074E56C6F8AF0 libm.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6D40000 00000000 00073000 651BEE1E6CC0192EFD3433073F18AA400 libc.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6DC2000 00000000 0008A000 9BE72DF41684E676935E3BC16AB7735A0 libc++.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6E51000 00000000 0002B000 E4E9C46973DBAFDC0819F2F8EEAA03A30 libwilhelm.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6E72000 00000000 000E8000 BA44F94CD1B13BCF4D51EF9CE2491B180 libandroid_runtime.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6F6B000 00000000 00029000 CE9BF1704BC89FDC3212385C78FA24F10 libbinder.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6F9D000 00000000 00007000 391BC346CD5EAACDC3DA2B984E6C620A0 liblog.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6FA6000 00000000 00018000 554761AD12BD10AEB8EAD2CC42701E6F0 libutils.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6FC1000 00000000 0000E000 34241C497479034737CFFEB8CDE3544F0 libcutils.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F6FD2000 00000000 00003000 02920370ECEBBA956FEB6272FCF884760 libsigchain.so
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: M F7003000 00000000 0001D000 D8C618B4EA36D959DC94F5939D5E46B80 linker
11-28 15:37:16.405 8798-8798/? A/google-breakpad: -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
11-28 15:37:16.425 412-533/br.com.mycompany.myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
11-28 15:37:16.425 412-533/br.com.mycompany.myapp W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
11-28 15:37:16.425 412-533/br.com.mycompany.myapp W/google-breakpad: 3.52
11-28 15:37:16.425 412-533/br.com.mycompany.myapp W/google-breakpad: 352
11-28 15:37:16.425 412-533/br.com.mycompany.myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
11-28 15:37:16.425 412-533/br.com.mycompany.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xf4c80d08 in tid 533 (Chrome_InProcRe)
11-28 15:37:16.485 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-28 15:37:16.485 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j7elteub/j7elte:6.0.1/MMB29K/J700MUBS2BQEB:user/release-keys'
11-28 15:37:16.485 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
11-28 15:37:16.485 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
11-28 15:37:16.485 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG: pid: 412, tid: 533, name: Chrome_InProcRe  >>> br.com.mycompany.myapp <<<
11-28 15:37:16.485 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xf4c80d08
11-28 15:37:16.525 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG:     r0 d4c80d04  r1 f6dc2ae0  r2 00000001  r3 ffffffe1
11-28 15:37:16.525 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG:     r4 07ffffff  r5 d4c80d0c  r6 46416026  r7 46416024
11-28 15:37:16.525 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG:     r8 f6dc2afc  r9 40000003  sl 00000003  fp f6dc2920
11-28 15:37:16.525 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000001  sp d837a690  lr f6d8b72b  pc f6d8996a  cpsr 00030030
11-28 15:37:16.535 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
11-28 15:37:16.535 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0004996a  /system/lib/libc.so (arena_run_reg_alloc+97)
11-28 15:37:16.535 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0004b727  /system/lib/libc.so (je_arena_tcache_fill_small+94)
11-28 15:37:16.535 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0005ca63  /system/lib/libc.so (je_tcache_alloc_small_hard+18)
11-28 15:37:16.535 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00057555  /system/lib/libc.so (je_malloc+1112)
11-28 15:37:16.535 22048-22048/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0030cad7  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
```

The full log is here: https://pastebin.com/1HUPjjer

The only thing I know is that it is webview/chromium related. I already tried to destroy the webview on activity's onDestroy, but no success.

Any ideas?